# Are there any light sources which the player may carry in the original Red Dead Redemption?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

The 'Undead Nightmare' DLC features a torch which can be both used as a weapon and equipped at will to illuminate surroundings. Having completed the base campaign and likely all side missions twice, I've never found a comparable item in the core game. Interior locations are relatively dim during daytime and while the nights obviously are far from pitch-black, as in most open world games, a source of light would at least be aesthetically pleasing.

---

The sequel (Red Dead Redemption 2, which I haven't truly played at the time of writing) in turn includes a lantern, fulfilling the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a [Game FAQs thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/957922-red-dead-redemption/54981503), there are no carriable light sources:

> Although that also makes me wish that John could at least carry a lamp with him!

> When I started the game I assumed it was supposed to be that dark, to give it realism but I also assumed you'd eventually be able to carry a Torch or Lantern.